# What happens when I do a pthread_mutex_init on an already locked pthread_mutex_t?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

My mutex class is defined:-

```
class Mutex{
    static pthread_mutex_t mutex;
public:
    Mutex(){
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
        while(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex)){
            sleep(2000);
        }
    }
    virtual ~Mutex(){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    }
};
```

The functions I am trying to apply the mutual exclusion to use this class like this:-

```
void doSomething(){
    Mutex mutex;
    // do something
}
```

This way when the constructor is called, the mutex is initialized and it tries to obtain the lock on that mutex. And when it goes out of scope from that function, it automatically gets destroyed.

But if one thread has a lock on the mutex, another thread tries to run `pthread_mutex_init` on it, what exactly happens? Will the thread that has the lock be overridden?

Comment: Nasal demons, of course.

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Answer is to short for answer :))

Comment: I'm trying to make sense out of what possible good could some from this implementation, and I can't find any. Also, unless you're still in pre-C++11-land, I see no earthly-or-otherwise reason not to be using [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and the rest of the offerings of the thread-support library.

Comment: @WhozCraig My software needs to support other softwares still in pre-C++11-land. It was a design requirement. Hence this implementation.

Comment: The loop around `pthread_mutex_trylock()` is silly: just call `pthread_mutex_lock()`, without the loop.

Comment: @caf Alright, I guess that was unnecessary. For some reason I thought that would prevent blockage of CPU usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty easy, from [POSIX.1-2013](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html):

> Attempting to initialize an already initialized mutex results in undefined behavior.

That's why you have an alternative way of initializing mutexes:

```
// in your .cpp somewhere
pthread_mutex_t Mutex::mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

---

Apart from this, logically speaking, your class seems very questionable. Do you really want to have *one* global lock for all users of `Mutex`, no matter what they're doing? You should employ fine grained locks, or you'll artificially limit your own scalability via [software lockout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_lockout).

Comment: This is just a mutex example I put up that would be used by a small part of the program. It *needs* to have a global lock for this implementation.